# php how to add months to a date?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to add months to a date using the following function

```
 date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+238 months", strtotime("2018-02-25"))) // gives the correct date as 2037-12-25
```

The function works when the I'm trying to add less than 238 months. When I tried to add a bigger number it gives the wrong answer as 1969-12-31.

```
 date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+239 months", strtotime("2018-02-25"))) // gives the wrong date as 1969-12-31.
```

If this is not the correct way to do, please suggest a function that works for the bigger months. Thank you.

Comment: It's the year 2038 bug

Comment: is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Yes. Use PHP's DateTime objects, or better yet, [the Carbon library](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). In Carbon, it'd be `Carbon::now()->addMonths(239)`.

Comment: DateTime works well $date->modify('+239 month'), thank you.

Comment: @Julia -  Indeed Carbon is simply a extension of DateTime, I've looked at the source code for it.  So why use the extension for something so simple?

Comment: I didn't use the Carbon library, I just used the built in DateTime.